# Dynamic EF Core Include equivalent to ThenInclude

Tags: c#, entity-framework

On ef core we can load a graph with..

```
DbContext.Player
.Include(a => a.Phones)
.Include(a => a.Addresses).ThenInclude(s => s.StateProvince).ThenInclude(c => c.CountryRegion)
.Include(a => a.EmailAddresses)
```

I am trying to build a dynamic graph as follows..

```
var expression = "Phones;Addresses,EmailAddresses";

 var includes = expression.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 var q = DbContext.Set<Player>().AsQueryable();

 foreach (var include in includes)
     q = q.Include(include);
```

but I can't include Address sub related entities, such StateProvince nor CountryRegion since I don't have ThenInclude construct.

How can I include sub related entities dynamically with ef core?

Comment: Include them like this: `Include("Addresses.StateProvince.CountryRegion")`

Comment: perfect it works!!